# Indexing equal/different elements in each row of a Matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a `IxJ` matrix `A` in Matlab which contains some numbers (possibly, including `Inf`, `-Inf`).

For example, for `I=3` and `J=6`, I could have

```
A=  [0    0      Inf -Inf 0   1; 
     5    4      Inf -Inf 6   5;
     Inf -Inf    0    Inf 0   2];
```

I want to construct a matrix `B` of size `IxJ`, such that each row `i` starts from `1`, adds a `+1` every time an element of `A(i,:)` changes, and assigns equal index to equal elements. Two `Inf` elements have to be treated as equal. Similarly, two `-Inf` elements have to be treated as equal.

In the example above

```
B=  [1 1 2 3 1 4;  %
     1 2 3 4 5 1;
     1 2 3 1 3 4];
```

Could you advise on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the third output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'stable'` option for each row:

```
B = NaN(size(A)); % preallocate
for k = 1:size(A,1)
   [~, ~, B(k,:)] = unique(A(k,:), 'stable');
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to avoid the loop? As in my actual case the length of `B` is `10^4`.

Comment: The only way I see to avoid a loop would require a 3D array, which could use a lot of memory. What are typical values for number of rows, number of columns and number of different values in the whole `A` matrix?

Comment: Thanks. Then the loop is better, for sure.